# Menu_block module on dashboard gives notice error which won't go away

Tags: routes

I'll installed the drupal block_module on my website, it works perfectly. Yesterday i decided to add this same block_module to drupals dashboard. Then all suddenly i got the following errors.

I iknow this is probably an issue of menu_block module or the dashboard or drupals core. How ever, i decided not to use the block_module for this purpose anymore. But even after deleting the block_module from the dashboard, i still recieve this errors.

I flushed all cache etc, but nothing seems to change... Can anyone suggest how to get rid of these nasty errors...

```
Notice: Undefined index: block-4-2 in menu_block_view() (regel 486 van C:\xampp\htdocs\website\modules\menu\menu.module).
Notice: Undefined index: block-4--2 in menu_block_view() (regel 486 van C:\xampp\htdocs\website\modules\menu\menu.module).
Notice: Undefined index: block-4-2--2 in menu_block_view() (regel 486 van C:\xampp\htdocs\website\modules\menu\menu.module).
Notice: Undefined index: block-4 in menu_block_view() (regel 486 van C:\xampp\htdocs\website\modules\menu\menu.module).
Notice: Undefined index: block-4-2 in dashboard_page_build() (regel 192 van C:\xampp\htdocs\website\modules\dashboard\dashboard.module).
Notice: Undefined index: block-4--2 in dashboard_page_build() (regel 192 van C:\xampp\htdocs\website\modules\dashboard\dashboard.module).
```